# PhpStorm 2016.2.2 - Creating new macros for file watchers

Tags: php, phpstorm

How to define new macros for file watchers? For example, I would like to add my own macro with path to `compass.bat` file. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK macros can be added by writing a plugin in Java. Macros are used for some dynamic stuff .. and yours does not look like one -- please describe your situation/problem which you are trying to resolve in first place.

Comment: It is dynamic. I would like to save `.idea/watcherTasks.xml` file on repository, to let all developers having the same file watchers configuration. But... each of them have different path to `compass.bat` file.

Comment: You can use existing **Path Variables** functionality (`Settings/Preferences | Appearance 7 Behavior | Path Variables`). Just set it up on ALL computers where it will be used -- each computer points to a folder where their local `compass.bat` is located. Once done -- just edit your File Watcher so that it is aware of that -- now while the path still displays as is on a screen, when saved in config file it will use that Path variable .. so when it will be opened on another computer it will use local value for that Path Variable.

Comment: Alternatively -- try adding path to the `compass.bat` into your global `PATH` variable (at least IDE restart might be required) and then use just `compass.bat` as program in File Watcher -- might also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like ***@LazyOne*** answered me in comments: I've added Path Variable and set "Program path" in File Watcher as `compass.bat`. Now I can add these settings to Git without a problem ;).